# Resources how to architect a iPhone application?

Tags: iphone, architecture

What resources can you recommend for learning how to architect a iPhone application?

Background of the question is that most of the resources explain the usage of a single class or concept (and i appreciate that a lot to learn something about the specific topic) but as far as i can see they lack unfortunately to describe how to put things together for typical real world applications.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This won't give you a ton of help with architecting large applications, but I found this site to be really useful for finding good examples for working with animations and all the ViewController stuff:  http://appsamuck.com/

Answer (score 1):

You should focus your search on best practices, as a lot of the details that go behind proper architecture are found in getting those general fundamentals right.

Otherwise, if you want to know how "typical real world applications" are designed, you should go and find some open source projects and download them. There will undoubtedly be a variation in quality but it should give you a general idea of how apps get built.

Overall I don't think you'll see a general tutorial on how to build an iPhone app because all applications are different. They solve different problems under different requirements for different kinds of users. You'll probably find that the answer to your question can only be found by trying to build something on your own.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I have to admit that my question is too unspecific, and consequently an answer will be also somehow more of general nature. I hope you don't mind that acceptance goes to Andy for sharing a concrete resource and you're getting an up-vote.